# Python Replace the contents of a regex capture group

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string:
`MY_VALUE=100OtherData=200`

And this regex:
`regex = r"MY_VALUE=(?P<value>\d+)"`

How can I use `re.sub` to replace the content of the captured group `value` without specyfing `MY_VALUE` before it, so it will result in:

`MY_VALUE=200OtherData=200`

Comment: `re.sub(r'(MY_VALUE=)\d+', r'\g<1>200', text)` / `re.sub(r'(?<=MY_VALUE=)\d+', '200', text)`

Comment: g<1> means group[1] ?

Comment: `\g<1>` is an *unambiguous* replacement backreference to Group 1